# How to Replace Div Content and have the JavaScript see the Replaced Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form on a page.

```
 <div id="form_catch">
<form id="form2">
<div><input type="button" value="Dear Diary" id="add" /><input type="button" 
value="Dear Friend" id="add_1" /></div>
<div><input type="text" id="salutations" name="salutations" value=""/></div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"  /> 
</form>
</div>
```

I use a javascript to manipulate this form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var form_box_copy = $('#form_catch').html()
  $("#add").click(function(){
      $('input#salutations').val('Dear Diary,');});
  $("#add_1").click(function(){
      $('input#salutations').val('Dear Friend,');});
      //console.log('test button');
$("form#form2").submit(function(evt){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); 
   $.ajax({
    url: 'http://wei.rocks/test2.html',
    type: 'GET',
    data:  {
      format: 'html'
   },
     enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
     processData: false,
     error: function(){alert('You Failed');},
     success: function (response) {
         alert('You passed');
          $('#form_catch').html(form_box_copy + "html replaced");
          $('#form_catch').append("Test222222222");}
   });


    return false;

})

})
```

When I run the page the scrip works as designed I ajax the form,  the task are successful. After success It replaces the form    with a fresh copy of it self.  All this work except when it is complete the Replacement of the form is no long working with the Java script.

Comment: What do you mean by "*is no long working with the JavaScript*"?

Comment: After the Content in The div id="form_catch" is replace the <input type="button" value="Dear Diary" id="add" /> no longer work as if the javascript lonlonger see them

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because when you replace the form with the new html, it discards the `submit` event registration attached to the form.

To bypass it you can either re-register the event or, as a better approach, register the event at the document level.

Simply change:

```
$("form#form2").submit(function(evt){
// your code
});
```

to:

```
  $(document).on('submit', '#form2', function(evt) {
// your code
    });
```

});

This should now work since the event is registered at the document level and not at the form level (and the document is never being replaced).

In general if you are replacing DOM elements, then the events registered to them will no longer work. This is why registering to the element's parent is a better approach (when needed).

See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXvKMv) for working example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your answer (codepen) the submit button does work after the replace.  The Salutation buttons do not work.

Comment: @ManuelKing they are not supposed to work in the demo, the demo just shows you how to make the submit button work.